# I want to read data from firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I tried a lot, but my data is not showing. when I put string instead of userID and NFID(userId and Nfid have same value.....but it can not read.

```
public class ClubInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_NFID= "com.hm.roktojoddha.EXTRA_NFID";
    public static final String EXTRA_MOBILE= "com.hm.roktojoddha.EXTRA_MOBILE";
    public static final String EXTRA_ID= "com.hm.roktojoddha.EXTRA_ID";
    public static final String EXTRA_CLUB= "com.hm.roktojoddha.EXTRA_CLUB";
    public static final String EXTRA_CLUB_FORM= "com.hm.roktojoddha.EXTRA_CLUB_FORM";
    FirebaseFirestore fstore;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    String userID,nfid;
    TextView club,title,descrip,date,time,place;
    Button form,page;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_club_info);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        nfid=intent.getStringExtra(FeedFragment.EXTRA_NFID);

        userID=intent.getStringExtra(FeedFragment.EXTRA_ID);
        Toast.makeText(ClubInfoActivity.this, ""+userID+" "+nfid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fstore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        club = findViewById(R.id.text7club);
        title = findViewById(R.id.text11club);
        descrip = findViewById(R.id.text17club);
        date = findViewById(R.id.text98club);
        time = findViewById(R.id.text95club);
        place =findViewById(R.id.textView100club);
        form = findViewById(R.id.button11);
        page = findViewById(R.id.button12);

      final  String  UI = userID;
      final  String NI =nfid;

        Toast.makeText(ClubInfoActivity.this, ""+UI+" "+NI, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Club_Detail").document(nfid).collection("History").document(nfid);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                club.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Club"));
                title.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Title"));
                descrip.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Description"));
                date.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Date"));
                time.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Time"));
                place.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Places"));
                String url_check=documentSnapshot.getString("URL");

                if (isValid(url_check)){
                 Toast.makeText(ClubInfoActivity.this, "Yes, URL is Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    form.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                else{
                  Toast.makeText(ClubInfoActivity.this, "NO, URL is not Valid/All", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    form.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });
```

[I am going from my feed news to another activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufaYv.png)

[Here no Data is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shtlA.png)

But when I compile this code

```
 DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Club_Detail").document("7").collection("History").document("202142200Vv1roiaUSQhttIRiyP60LxZd4Hk2");
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                club.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Club"));
                title.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Title"));
                descrip.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Description"));
                date.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Date"));
                time.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Time"));
                place.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Places"));
                String url_check=documentSnapshot.getString("URL");

                if (isValid(url_check)){
                 Toast.makeText(ClubInfoActivity.this, "Yes, URL is Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    form.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                else{
                  Toast.makeText(ClubInfoActivity.this, "NO, URL is not Valid/All", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    form.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
```

[It work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERv96.png)

But I don't want in this way.

Comment: sorry ....i don't mean that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is you're using same `String` variable for document names. In your first code (which you're saying it's not working) you're using `nfid` `String` variable  as a document name for both documents.

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Club_Detail").document(nfid).collection("History").document(nfid);
```

But in other code (which you're adding document names manually) you're using different values for each document.

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Club_Detail").document("7").collection("History").document("202142200Vv1roiaUSQhttIRiyP60LxZd4Hk2");
```

EDIT:

> Toast message showing wrong order i write it according to my firestore
> database i create Club_Detail then userId which is 7 for one user then
> history then nfid as serial and that nfid string

```
DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("Club_Detail").document(userID).collection("History").document(nfid);
```

Comment: toast message showing wrong order

i write it according to my firestore database i create Club_Detail then userId which is 7 for one user then history then nfid as serial and that nfid string

Comment: My point was you're using wrong document names. You showed two DocumentReferences and  document names are different even for same document. That's what i wanted to say. According to your comment edited my answer and changed document names.

Comment: first one you see it shown from another activity and last one you see is after open that activity.......  two are different

Comment: Eventhough Activities are different you're using same String variable (nfid) for different documents. You're saying codes are belong to two different Activities but database is same so according to your codes, collections and documents are same or have similar structure but for document names in first Activity you're passing same String variable but in second Activity document names are totally different. Either your first Activity has a wrong document names or your second Activity has a wrong document names.

Comment: if(category.equals("Club")){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClubInfoActivity.class);

                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NFID, n_fid);

                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);

                            startActivity(intent);

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+id+" "+n_fid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

Comment: https://ibb.co/nL0H8Xz
https://ibb.co/k2xzLQ5
https://ibb.co/QNrwkLP

Comment: from the feedfragment, data is tranfer to clubinfoactivity......but everything is working.......i remembered......i tried this method and succeed....but now it is not working

Comment: can you also share userID2's and nfid2's values? also check if document exists or not.

Comment: document is exist.......in picture you can see.....but why this is happening today.....i remember it was working.....i am confused

Comment: thanks man......firestore data entry problem....i had problem on that